# CANopen, TPDO and RPDO behavior?

Tags: can-bus, canopen

[image]

Say I have deviceA(NodeID 1) and deviceB(NodeID2)

- Does deviceA send TxPDO 180+2 and deviceB receive data by RxPDO 200+2
- Does deviceA send TxPDO 280+2 and deviceB receive data by RxPDO 300+2
- Does RxPDO send data to cable? Or it just eds file?

PS, photo is from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CANopen

Answer (score 0):

The NodeIDs are only added to PDOs sent, not received by the associated node.

Therefore:

*Does deviceA send TxPDO 180+2 and deviceB receive data by RxPDO 200+2*
**No, DeviceA sends 180+1, and DeviceB receives 200+1 (because if he receives, he cannot be sender, and you said only 2 nodes are on the bus, thus the only ID possible to be added is 1).**

*Does deviceA send TxPDO 280+2 and deviceB receive data by RxPDO 300+2*
No, same explanation as above.
Does RxPDO send data to cable? Or it just eds file?
RxPDO was sent by cable.

Comment: Thank you for replying. So the sender(DeviceA) can't control who can receive data and receiver(DeviceB) can decide to listen to who?
I thought only TxPDO broadcast to cable and RxPDO is for listening(receive TxPDO)?

Answer (score 0):

The COB-ID list for PDOs shows only the default values. If all devices in a network have default COB-IDs for their PDOs, it means that they are not linked together and no device listens to any PDO sent on the bus (well, actually the PDOs they listen to simply don't exist on the bus). Default COB-IDs ensure that there is no COB-ID conflict on the bus.

Usually, a CANopen master configures the bus using SDO request by changing TPDO and RPDO COB-IDs in each device. So, DeviceA sends TPDO with 180+1 and if you want DeviceB to listen to DeviceA, you set DeviceB's RPDO COB-ID to 180+1 as well.

One may think that after the nodes are connected together, some default RPDO COB-IDs become unused (or wasted). Devices can use them as TPDO COB-IDs, if there are more than 4 TPDOs are needed. Of course, there are other ways to increase the number of TPDOs.